# GameMaker Studio 2; Weapon System. Error: DoConv :1: illegal undefined/null use; how to fix it?

Tags: var, gml, game-maker-studio-2

Im trying to implement a weapon switching system in GameMaker Studio 2 and I'm following a tutorial to do so since I'm not too experienced with GML.
When I'm trying to run this script I'm getting the following error, and I can't find a way to get it to work.

############################################################################################
ERROR in
action number 1
of Create Event
for object :

DoConv :1: illegal undefined/null use
at gml_GlobalScript_ChangeWeapon (line 2) - var wp_map = weapons[weapon];
############################################################################################
gml_GlobalScript_ChangeWeapon (line 2)

And the script is:

```
weapon = argument0;
var wp_map = weapons[weapon];
sprite = wp_map[? "sprite"];
recoil = wp_map[? "recoil"];
recoil_push = wp_map[? "recoil_push"];
damage = wp_map[? "damage"];
projectile = wp_map[? "projectile"];
startup = wp_map[? "startup"];
bulletspeed = wp_map[? "bulletspeed"];
length = wp_map[? "length"];
cooldown = wp_map[? "cooldown"];
automatic = wp_map[? "automatic"];
```

Answer (score 2):

This error may mean a few things:

- You did not wrap the contents of the script in `function <name>() { ... }` (as per the message that you get when you create new scripts in 2.3), causing your code to be executed on game start (and, surely enough, without arguments)
- You called your script without an argument (`ChangeWeapon()` vs `ChangeWeapon(arg)`).
- You called your script with an argument, but argument's value is `undefined`.

Based on the error message, I would assume this to be the first of three.